Why does a trapped matplotlib 'close_event' continue to kill my window
I'm working on a larger project where I have several plots. I'm able to iconify the plots so it doesn't clutter up the screen. I would like to disable the close (X) and instead have it just iconify the plot. Using  mpl_connect() I was expecting to catch the event and process the 'close_event' and that be the end if it, but that is not what happens. In the attached code, if you show both plots and close one of them with the (X). It iconifys one but kills the one that was clicked.
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

# make some data
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
sinx = np.sin(8.0*np.pi*x)
cosx = np.cos(8.0*np.pi*x)

def showPlot1():
    plotMng1.window.deiconify()
    
def hidePlot1():
    plotMng1.window.iconify()

def showPlot2():
    plotMng2.window.deiconify()

def hidePlot2():
    plotMng2.window.iconify()

def handle_close(event):
    # Prevent the default close behavior
    print("my handler called by {}".format(event))
    plotMng1.window.iconify()
    plotMng2.window.iconify()

def quitAll():
    plt.close()
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()
    
# make an instance of Tk    
root = tk.Tk()
plt.ion()

# generate a plot
fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots()
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)  # catch the close event
axs1.plot(x,sinx,'-', label="sin")
axs1.set_xlim(0,1)
axs1.set_ylim(-1,1)
axs1.legend(loc="upper right")
plotMng1 = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
plotMng1.window.iconify()

# generate another plot
fig2, axs2 = plt.subplots()
fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)  # catch the close event
axs2.plot(x,cosx,'-', label="cos")
axs2.set_xlim(0,1)
axs2.set_ylim(-1,1)
axs2.legend(loc="upper right")
plotMng2 = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
plotMng2.window.iconify()

tk.Button(root, text="Show 1",padx = 20, command=showPlot1).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Hide 1",padx = 20, command=hidePlot1).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Show 2",padx = 20, command=showPlot2).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Hide 2",padx = 20, command=hidePlot2).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Quit",padx = 20, command=quitAll).pack()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quitAll)
root.mainloop()


what happens is that the event "close_event" is called after the window is actually closed, so when you try to iconify the window, well it's already closed.
mpl_connect was a good try but unfortunately you won't achieve what you want to do.
What you want to do is interact with the fig_manager instead of the canvas, and react to the event "WM_DELETE_WINDOW" that is triggered right before actually closing the window.
In consequence, the plot definitions should be as following (remove the line where you call mpl_connect and add the new method):
fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots()
axs1.plot(x, sinx, '-', label="sin")
axs1.set_xlim(0, 1)
axs1.set_ylim(-1, 1)
axs1.legend(loc="upper right")
plotMng1= plt.get_current_fig_manager()
#Add the following line in every plot definition
plotMng1.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handle_close)
plotMng1.window.iconify()

and you have to adapt the handle_close function subsequently (as it doesn't take any argument now):
def handle_close():
    plotMng1.window.iconify()
    plotMng2.window.iconify()

(you could as well define a handle_close function for each plot depending on the behavior you want, I just sticked to your example)

Thanks. This worked. I suspected something like this, so I tried plotMng1.window.bind(), which didn't work.

If you find my answer useful consider accepting it !
